# Why is my js function prompts not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to execute a function that displays the biggest of three numbers but to display it in a html element. But to get the arguments via prompt().
Here is my code:

```js
function maxNumber(num1, num2, num3) {
  var sorry = "none";

  if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3) {
    return num1;
  } else if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3) {
    return num2;
  } else if (num3 > num1 && num3 > num2) {
    return num3;
  } else if (num1 == num2 || num2 == num3 || num3 == num1) {
    return sorry.none;
  }
  document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = maxNumber(prompt("First Number?"), prompt("Second Number?"), prompt("Third Number?"));
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="maxNumber()">Which is the biggest number?</a>
<h1 id="num">Biggest number</h1>
```

So when I click on the "a" tag the prompts should pop-up and ask for the numbers but they don't even pop-up.

Comment: You call a function with signature `maxNumber()` - without arguments. However, you've defined only `maxNumber(num1,num2,num3)`. Your function also has a weird recursive call inside, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Hint: Use [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Comment: Why do you expect a string to have a property called `.none`?  What would happen if your function returns before its inner recursive call?  This is *very* strangely structured.

Comment: Note: This is also a *great* opportunity for you to familirize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Take a look at your browser's debugging tools.  The console will tell you of any errors during JavaScript execution.  And you can set breakpoints in the code and step through it, line by line, as it executes to observe the runtime values and behaviors.  When you do this, when you place a breakpoint inside your function and watch what it does, what does it do?  When does its behavior differ from what you expected?  What did you expect?  Why?

Comment: The strange thing is that the console shows no mistakes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Math.max to get the biggest value

```js
function maxNumber() {
  var num1 = prompt("First Number?");
  var num2 = prompt("Second Number?");
  var num3 = prompt("Third Number?");

  document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = Math.max(num1, num2, num3);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="maxNumber()">Which is the biggest number?</a>
<h1 id="num">Biggest number</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer. That will do it,  although i wanted to know why mine is not working.

Comment: In your code you are checking for the max value before even calling the prompt(), and you are calling the  maxNumber() without setting arguments ...!!

Comment: move your script inside the <body> and below the id

Answer (score 0):

```js
            function maxNum() {
                var first = prompt("First Number?"),
                    second = prompt("Second Number?"),
                    third = prompt("Third Number?"),
                    maxNo = Math.max(first, second, third);
                
                document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = 'Biggest number' + maxNo;
            }
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="maxNum()">Which is the biggest number?</a>
<h1 id="num">Biggest number</h1>
```